# Selenium:With selelenium RC can we scroll the scrollbar up or down

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Can we use Selenium RC to move the browser's scroll bar up or down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever you can do with Javascript could be done with Selenium RC 1.X.

The reason being, it provides a bridge between Client Driver/Program environment and the Browser Javascript Engine context.

consider Java and Selenium RC 1.x environment.

selenium.getEval("window.scrollTo(0,0)");

that simple.

If you actually want to take control of Scroll Bar, i don't know now. This is, you are working on document through Window and it indirectly moves the Scroll bar.

hope i have resolved